# Sum of series of real numbers.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to find the sum of the series $$1+\frac{1}{3.4}+\frac{1}{5.4^{2}}+\frac{1}{7.4^{3}}\cdot\cdot\cdot$$ What is the idea behind to find the sum of this type of series? How i think to compare it to other known series like log series etc.? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you read $x=1/4$ then I see the series $1+\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x^2}{5}+\frac{x^3}{7}...$ Can you find out what series this is?

Comment: See [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the MacLaurin series for $\ln(1+x)$,
$$x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots,$$ 
and the series for $\ln(1-x)$, 
$$x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots.$$
Add, divide by $2$. We get
$$\frac{1}{2}(\ln(1+x)+\ln(1-x))=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+\frac{x^7}{7}+\cdots.$$
Divide by $x$, and make the appropriate choice for $x$.

Comment: all right....beat me...+1

Comment: yes i got the point....thanking you a lot....

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: there is minus between logs...

Comment: @neela: Thanks, I think the typo is fixed. I had aimed for } and missed, twice.

Comment: The important thing is to get your answer in first. You can always make it correct later:)

Comment: Check your expansion of $\ln(1-x)$ please.